# GIT: fetch-merge vs pull

Tags: java, git, version-control

I understand that `fetch-merge` and pull are the same thing, however sometimes by doing `fetch-merge` I get some conflicts which I would not get if I just did `pull`.
Does anybody know why?

Comment: How do you know that one way handles conflicts the other does not?

Comment: @Raffaele I first always try fetch-merge, and sometimes it gives me conflicts, then I try pull (without solving conflicts) and it works.

Comment: Please define "it gives me conflicts" and "it works" -  also, do you have any reproducible example? Like, a public repo on GitHub and two commits

Comment: @Raffaele Unfortunally I don't have a reproducible example, however It happened to me more than once and wanted to know if was a common issue. From your comments I am assuming you have never come across this kind of problems.

Comment: The main problem here is lack of input: you say *it works*, *it gives me conflicts*, but these are subjective terms, and you don't have a test case. Maybe the messages you see/don't see come from running one command after another in the same working tree

Comment: Is it possible to get **the exact commands** that you're using to fetch and merge vs pull?